# Pushforward of the structure sheaf - Justification of a reduction argument

Tags: algebraic-geometry

While reading Katz and Mazur's book "Arithmetic Moduli of Elliptic Curves" (available [here](http://math.bu.edu/people/jsweinst/AWS/Files/KatzMazurArithmeticModuli.pdf)), I came across the following statement (p.65).

> Let $S$ be an arbitrary scheme and let $E$ be a proper smooth curve over $S$ with geometrically connected fiber. Let $f$ denote the morphism $E\rightarrow S$. Then, we have $$f_{\star}(\mathcal{O}_E)=\mathcal{O_S}$$
>   Hence, if $\mathcal{L}$ is some invertible sheaf defined on an open subset $U\subset S$, we have the equality of invertible sheaves on $U$ $$f_{\star}f^{\star}(\mathcal{L})=\mathcal{L}$$

The second point is a consequence of the first by the projection formula.

For the first point, I think one may reduce to the case where $S$ is the spectrum of an algebraically closed field $k$. Then, to prove the isomorphism of sheaves over $k$, we only have to prove the isomorphism between the rings of global sections. It is then a known result that any global section of a connected reduced proper $k$-scheme with $k=\overline{k}$ is a constant, which is exactly what we want (see for instance Vakil's note, 10.3.7, page 289, [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf)).

However, I am really unsure about the justification of the reduction to this case. In order to prove that the natural morphism $\mathcal{O}_S \rightarrow f_{\star}\mathcal{O}_E$ is an isomorphism, I would like to show that this map induces isomorphism between sections on open subsets or (equivalently) between stalks. How does one reduces to just looking at fibers and, even more specifically, geometric fibers?

I thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What happens if you try to upgrade Vakil's reasoning and use an arbitrary base scheme instead of $\operatorname{Spec} \overline{k}$?

Comment: @KReiser Exactly, that is eventually the point of Katz & Mazur's construction.

Comment: My comment meant that running the exact same proof should work: $S$-functions on $E$ are maps to $\Bbb A^1_S$, and composing with the obvious inclusion $\Bbb A^1_S\to \Bbb P^1_S$ gives a proper map $E\to \Bbb P^1_S$ factoring through an affine subset, and therefore the map must be a finite collection of points. As $E$ is irreducible, it's image must be as well, so every $S$-function on $E$ descends to a function on $S$, which is exactly what you want to prove.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @KReiser. I have two questions about this proof. First of all, how can we guarantee that the map $E\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1_S$ is proper? Actually, I realized that I do not understand this part even in Vakil's proof. The result he is referring to starts by assuming that a composition is proper, whereas this is exactly the result we want. As far as I know, the only way to show that a composition is proper is to show that each morphism is (which is not true here, we have an open immersion). Secondly, how do you know that $E$ is irreducible? In what hypothesis does it lie?

Comment: As far as $E\to \Bbb P^1_S$ being proper: this is 10.3.4e in Vakil. We prove that for $f:X\to Y$ a morphism of $Z$-schemes, if $X$ is proper and $Y$ is separated, then $X\to Y$ is proper. (In the following, all products are fiber products over $Z$.) This follows because $X\times Y \to Y$ is closed as $X$ is proper, and $X\to X\times Y$ by $x\mapsto (x,f(x))$ is closed because it's the base change of the diagonal $Y\to Y\times Y$ along $f\times id: X\times Y\to Y\times Y$. Usually texts have curve meaning irreducible scheme of dim 1, so I assumed it from there.

Comment: Aaaah, I got it! I was misunderstanding the way one uses this proposition about properness. Then, everything is ok. Thank you very much again!

Comment: Hmm @KReiser can you elaborate on your argument?.. for example it's not the case that closed subsets of $\mathbb{P}^1_S$ are a finite collection of points, and also $E$ needs not to be irreducible if e.g. $S$ is not irreducible. Perhaps I misunderstood something?

In any case, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63301/when-will-the-pushforward-of-a-structure-sheaf-still-be-a-structure-sheaf suggests a solution for the original problem in the comments of OP "For a flat projective [or proper] morphism, it suffices to have geometrically connected and geometrically reduced fibres".

Comment: It is the case that all closed $S$-subschemes of $\Bbb P^1_S$ are either a finite collection of $S$-points of $\Bbb P^1_S$ itself. As for irreducibility, I did slightly mistype. It's not true that $f(E)$ must necessarily be irreducible, but it is true that $f(E)$ must be (geometrically) connected, and in $\Bbb P^1_S$, (geometrically) 
 connected is equivalent to (geometrically) irreducible.

Comment: The map $O_S \to f_*O_E$ is surjective on fibers as you said, and then Nakayama’s lemma gives surjectivity on stalks. Injecttivity follows as I assume $f$ is faithfully flat.